# gtags not respecting .ctags file

Tags: emacs, global, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I have built globals with universal-ctags. I could verify that when executing ctags --version i get the universal-ctags version and not any other.

I have created a .ctags file that contains:

```
-R
-exclude=foo
```

When executing gtags I don't see it respecting the .ctags file. instead it just go ahead and extract tags for everything in the working directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This facility was news to me, but I presume you are referring to https://www.gnu.org/software/global/manual/global.html#Plug_002din ?

Comment: Yes Phils, that is what I am referring to. Although I am struggling with gtags picking up the universal-ctags exclude.ctags file. Also I don't want to use the "skip" untility inside gtags.conf